# How to test linux variable within sed file?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I have a sed file that contains contains a few substitutions, it is executed on a file using the following syntax:

```
sed -f mysedfile file.txt > fixed_file.txt
```

I would like to test a system variable and depending what that variable contains, execute different sed operations on file.txt.

Would it be possible to put this logic into mysedfile?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I doubt this is possible with [tag:sed]. You'd need to call a shell script, check the variables there and call [tag:sed] from this script.

Comment: You're probably better off using `awk` or `perl`.

Answer (score 1):

Perl was explicitly created to get around limitations of sed and awk. The `-p` mode runs a script for each line in the file. You can put it on the commandline:

```
perl -p -e "s/foo/\$ENV{'HOME'}/e" < files.txt
```

Or move the script to a file (you can remove the '`\`' before the `$`)

```
perl -p file.pl < files.txt
```

Or make the first line of your script like this so you can run it directly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
```